# Fire base not call onCancelled if timeout or not able to access server

Tags: java, android, firebase

I a using firebase and found and issue that firebase not send error for timeout or if not able to connect to server. In that case we are unable to provide correct information to user what the issue is.

Firebase developers must handle this very common use-case. Did anyone encounter this issue?

```
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {

            }
```

Answer (score 6):

Utilize `.info/connected` to monitor connection state. Firebase works while offline and your onCancelled event is not going to be fired because it is still waiting for the connection to be restored so the message can be delivered.

Firebase is a real-time sync platform. You cannot keep data in sync without any internet access (how will local and remote be reconciled?). So you need to utilize disk persistence (in beta on iOS) or at least have an initial connection to get things moving. Check out [offline capabilities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html) for details on all of these topics.